# A shevah after a Shooruk (milupim) at the beginning of word

Tags: grammar-dikduk

This may seem like a simple question but I took a poll and asked some people I know how they pronounce the word וּנְסַפֵּר. I personally say U-N-sa-per. Others said like me and others say Un-sa-per. I figured this must be a machlokes about whether a shavah that is after a shoorok (milupim) is silent or not. Does anyone have some good sources on this?

Comment: I've seen 3 opinions but never traced them further: always nach (Simanim), always na (older siddurim), only na if the shuruk has a meseg (Artscroll).

Comment: Thanks for that info,looking more for Rishonim,Achronim type sources